# Math Research Opportunities for a Senior in High School

Tags: research

I'm a 17-year old senior in high school who will most likely be attending USC next year. I have experience in single, and multivariable calculus, linear algebra, some topology and some abstract algebra. I am passionate about math and wish to continue studying it. The past four years in high school I have applied to various math research summer programs for high school students and have gotten rejected every time. I also got rejected by many of the very competitive colleges. I don't have any research experience but I want to research. Is this possible? What are some possibilities for me? Who can/should I contact if I want to research during the summer?

Comment: You should come to UCLA instead there’s plenty opportunities :]

Answer (score 11):

I would hold off on research for a few years.

Instead, I would focus on study, with the goal of truly *mastering* the courses ahead.

Start in the summer on the courses you plan to take next year. Do a few chapters worth for each course, with an emphasis on strengthening your problem-solving and proof skills. Try for depth, and definitely attempt the more challenging exercises. Write down questions of your own as they arise (as the beginning of a research mentality), and of the ones you can't answer, keep them in reserve for the future.

Following that plan, you will hopefully be an outstanding student on day one.

Comment: Thank you for specific advice!

Answer (score 4):

You should contact the math department of your local university.  If there isn't one nearby, or if nobody there is willing to work with you, then I'm afraid you'll need to wait until you're in college.

Comment: I will definitely attempt this. Thank you.